# Importing csv file into neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I am beggining with neo4j and i have a problem for importing some data from a csv file.

My code is the following :

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (w:word) ASSERT w.stem IS UNIQUE

USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
     LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:/home/quentin/.pfe/short_abstracts_fr0.csv" AS row
     MATCH (a:article {title: row.article})
     MATCH (w:word {stem: row.word})
     MERGE (a)-[r:contains {count:row.count}]->(w)
```

This is not creating any error, but it doesn't import anything. My csv file location is the good one, and it's content is the following :

```
article,word,count
Aux_couleurs_du_Moyen_Âge,accompagné,1
Aux_couleurs_du_Moyen_Âge,auss,1
Aux_couleurs_du_Moyen_Âge,banquet,1
```

I have already imported 2 similar csv files using : :

```
   USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
     LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:/home/quentin/.pfe/category_relations_csv" AS row
     MATCH (a:article {title: row.article})
     MATCH (cat:category {label: row.categorie})
     MERGE (a)-[:is_under]->(cat)
```

and

```
    MATCH (c0:category {label: row.cat0})
     MATCH (c1:category {label: row.cat1})
     MERGE (c0)-[r:relates {type:row.link}]->(c1)"
```

If someone has any idea what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you confirmed that it is matching `a` and `w`? If one or both of `a` and `w` is not being found then your `MERGE` statement will not create anything. Try outputting the results, rather than attempting the `MERGE`.
e.g.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:/home/quentin/.pfe/short_abstracts_fr0.csv" AS row
MATCH (a:article {title: row.article}), (w:word {stem: row.word})  
RETURN a.article, w.word
```

If you know that they do not already exist then you can omit the `MATCH` clauses.

e.g.

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (w:word) ASSERT w.stem IS UNIQUE

USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:/home/quentin/.pfe/short_abstracts_fr0.csv" AS row
MERGE (a:article {title: row.article})-[r:contains {count:row.count}]->(w:word {stem: row.word})
```

Likewise, if you expect that only one end of the pattern will already exist then include only one `MATCH` clause. From your query and addition of a constraint, it looks like you may be expecting the creation of the node with the `:Word` label. If so your query could look like this.

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (w:word) ASSERT w.stem IS UNIQUE

USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:/home/quentin/.pfe/short_abstracts_fr0.csv" AS row
MATCH (a:article {title: row.article})
MERGE (a)-[r:contains {count:row.count}]->(w:word {stem: row.word})
```

However, it may be better to create the nodes first and then create the relationship pattern. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think I had a problem during my installation of Neo4j, because after I uninstalled it and re-installed it, my import finally worked.